# How to add custom response to rest api "_create()" function in Magento?

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add additional response to **_create** function of Magento Rest API. While adding **return "Message"** , it is showing in **Header Location** for Oauth object but I need to return my custom message.

[image: _create function Header Response]

Comment: This might help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54576/14992